How to combine two shopify blocks into a single block with a left float OR surround these in a container so i can float with CSS
I'm building our new site, and the directors want the add to cart button and quanity selector to be side by side. However my theme doesnt have an option for this, and I've been struggling to build a custom block / combine the two blocks together in backend.
For me, if there is a way to easily surround these two blocks in a parent container I can then easily use flexbox in custom css section, however I have no idea how to do this via Liquid or the template JSON files.
Any help would be aprechiated. Images attached of the current look vs the mockup we want to get:

Below is how we want it to look:

I have tried to make a custom block, but I've never done this before, and ChatGPT isnt helping lol
